# install a library for python

Tags: python, installation

i'm trying to install a library for python of gene ontology programming [GOGrapher]. In the page they told me this:

```
$ `svn co https://projects.dbbe.musc.edu/public/GOGrapher/trunk GOGrapher`
$ cd GOGrapher
$ su -
# python setup.py install
```

I do everything, but in the last step a get an error

```
error: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/GOGrapher-0.0.egg-info: Permission denied
```

What is wrong? I'm new on this, but I do what I can.

Comment: You definitely did the `su` step?

Comment: no, on ubuntu. In the step su - ask me for a password, i put my password and fail. But i think thats not the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

instead. (Works for me on Mac OS 10.7.3, while the suggested `su -` solution doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to install things as superuser in the filesystem.  In Python you can always install libraries locally.

Assuming you are already in GOGrapher directory:

```
$ python setup.py install --home
```

should install the library in your home directory.  Later, you have to add the library PATH to the PYTHONPATH environment variable, so Python will know where to search for it.

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/lib/python
```

The directory might be slightly different (lib/python2.7 or even lib/python2.7/site-packages), you can check it, tough.

To make it permanent, you should add it in your .profile, .bashrc, or whatever is the shell you are using.

Comment: i will try this. I dont know so much about python, but receiving answers like this i will upgrade my level [sorry for my english] Thanks!